# Ajax fails on URL.createObjectURL in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm using the createObjectURL API to create a URL for a xml string and then call it using an ajax call. This works for me on Chrome, IE and Safari, but not on FireFox.

```
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ sContent ]));
$.get(objectURL, function(data){alert(data);});
```

I see a difference in the objectURL coming from firefox and other browsers: 
in firefox it looks like e.g. : "blob:6e777778-32d2-4477-80d5-fbdeef5bbd74" 
but on all other browsers: "blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/663c1b26-5e98-4433-863e-425e7cbc7471"

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can get it working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? What is the value of sContent in the different browsers?

Comment: I'm using version 32.0.3 of Firefox. And the value of sContent is a XML string.

Comment: Can you try explicitly declaring the blob as type text/xml by passing `{type : 'text/xml'}` as the second parameter of your Blob constructor?

Comment: Tried it, and still got the same result.. i see a difference in the objectURL coming from firefox and other browsers: in firefox it looks like: "blob:6e777778-32d2-4477-80d5-fbdeef5bbd74" but on all other browsers: "blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/663c1b26-5e98-4433-863e-425e7cbc7471"

Comment: Could you give the code that generates sContent as well? I think the problem is somewhere there.

Comment: sContent can be: "<tagA>aa</tagA>"

Comment: Just give the entire method that you pulled those 2 lines from, not just those 2 lines that you gave here. The problem is that something goes wrong when you're generating your sContent string, and that Guid that the blob gives cannot POSSIBLY come from that what you say it can be. What does <tagA>aa</tagA> even mean? You give that without context. I'm just trying to help you, but you need to give much more information.

Comment: OK, the sContent is a metadata.xml. An example is the OData northwind service: http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata Thanks a lot btw for your help